# libgdx - Handling different screen resolutions and sizes?

Tags: libgdx, screen-resolution, screen-size

I have created an app that uses FitViewport. So it will keep the aspect ratio on any phone.

But how do I solve that for my fonts? My buttons etc are all scaled to look the same bu the fonts are not.
So I need some solutions with different font sizes for different screen resolutions.

What is the way to handle that in libgdx?

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic font sizes, either you can use multiple BitmapFont files for each resolution or use [Gdx-freetype](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gdx-freetype) and generate them on the fly.